# cPanel wildcard redirect for whole domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains, one is the old domain and the other is the newest one.

Whats the best way using the `.htaccess` file to redirect ALL urls on the old domains to the new domain

for example if i go to `old-domain.com/test` it would redirect to `new-domain.com/test` or if i went to `sub.old-domain.com` it would redirect to `sub.new-domain.com`

Comment: @doublesharp is correct... per SO courtesy, please accept his solution...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) rule and the `%{HTTP_HOST}` parameter to match on the "old" domain and redirect to the "new" one if needed. If it matches, use a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)  to create a wildcard matching group to perform a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?old-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

Test with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
input url
http://old-domain.com/test

output url
http://www.new-domain.com/test

debugging info
1 RewriteEngine on  
2 RewriteBase / 
3 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?old-domain\.com [NC]
  This condition was met
4 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
  This rule was met, the new url is http://www.new-domain.com/test
  The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect
```

Comment: can this also do sub domains?

Comment: Yes, you just need to use the proper regex for the subdomain in the rewritecond

Comment: do you have an example for this please?

Comment: In my example it would match `www.old-domain.com` or `old-domain.com`, you could just change this to be `subdomain.old-domain.com` for example (remove the matching group parens and `?`)